# How do I check if a module on CPAN is newer than the one I've bundled in my project?

Tags: perl, version, cpan

I've written a program which uses some CPAN modules and I ship these modules inside a folder called `inc`.

Now, I would love to write a script to help me to maintain this project. The script should check if on CPAN a newer version of the modules I've bundled is available.

I've noticed that some of these modules have a `$VERSION` variable which I could easily extract from them (some of them, however, haven't it). But how could I extract the same information from CPAN?

Comment: Don't you afraid, that newer module's versions will break your project on production?

Comment: @Suic, no, I don't want it to be automatically installed. I just want a script which automatically checks this for me and acknowledge me whether it's available or not. Then, I'll upgrade it by hand and properly test it.

Answer (score 2):

To find the latest version of a module on CPAN, you can download the `modules/02packages.details.txt.gz` from any CPAN mirror.

```
...
Acme::AutoColor                    0.03  C/CA/CAVAC/Acme-AutoColor-0.03.tar.gz
Acme::AwesomeQuotes                0.02  C/CA/CARWASH/Acme-AwesomeQuotes-0.02.tar.gz
Acme::Base64                     v0.0.2  H/HA/HAGGAI/Acme-Base64-v0.0.2.tar.gz
Acme::BDFOY                        0.01  B/BD/BDFOY/Acme-BDFOY-0.01.tar.gz
Acme::Be::Modern                   0.03  S/SL/SLU/Acme-Be-Modern-0.03.tar.gz
...
```

Comment: To compare versions, compare objects returned by `$version_obj = version->parse($version_str);`

Answer (score 1):

You may get this info with this command: `cpanp -o`